# jquery Chosen not rendered after row cloned

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone, jquery-chosen

I'm having a nightmare of a time trying to get the jQuery Chosen plugin to render correctly after a table row has been cloned. I have scoured and tried many suggestions and 'guaranteed fixes' but can get nothing to work.

Depending on my attempts, I'm either able to get a standard select box to display (or not), or I can manage to show a Chosen select box, which only controls the original row :(

Here is the latest which removes the pre-existing chosen div, and displays a standard select box.

Please note I am able to render all other selects as a Chosen select by simply adding the class required - 'chosen-select', 'chosen-select-no-single' etc, document.ready creates sets chosen() on each object with any chosen-select class

**HTML** row to be cloned:

```
   <tr id='formListRow' class='row'>
    <td><input id='itmDesc0' name='itmDesc0' class='long lockableField' type='text' placeholder='Description' value=''></td>
    <td>
     <select id='itmCategory0' name='itmCategory0' class='chosen-select-no-single'>   
      <options></option>
     </select>
    </td>
   </tr>
```

**JS**

```
var $row = document.getElementById("formListRow"); // find row to copy
var $newRow = jQuery($("#formListRow")).clone (true); // copy children too
$newRow.attr('id','newRow' + itm); // change id or other attributes/contents
$newRow.find('select').each(function(){
  $(this).removeClass().removeAttr('id').css('display','block').next().remove();
  $(this).attr('name','itmCategory' + itm);
  $(this).attr('id','itmCategory' + itm);
  $(this).addClass('chosen-select-no-single');
  $(this).chosen();
});


$("#formListRow").before($newRow);
```

Guidance is super appreciated. 
JP

**UPDATE**

Creating another function for testing purposes so that the Chosen plugin can be applied to the newly cloned element after its been inserted is also not making a lick of difference:

```
function setNewChosen(itm){
    $(".chosen-select-no-single").last().chosen();
}
```

Comment: you have to apply plugin after you dynamically insert new elements

Comment: you have typed in lots. But, I can't get the idea of you looking. "_"

Comment: @yeshansachithak ....thanks for the input.... I've tried various from the below

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20671718/chosen-plugin-options-are-not-passed-to-cloned-row

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17902507/how-can-i-clone-chosen-plugin

https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/795

https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/271

Comment: @charlietfl adding $(this).chosen() in the find('select') function makes no difference if this is what you mean?

Comment: @user3758772 I wanted to know what do you want to do? Can you explain it by point view. Like, when user click that, when user do this.

Comment: @user3758772 no because that isn't after the html is inserted

Comment: @yeshansachithak gotcha. I have table row consisting of this and a few other columns, for adding expenses. A user can click a button 'add rpw' which calls the JS function to clone the row, so that another expense item can be entered. The select drop down contains a list of categories. nothing more to it than that

Comment: @charlietfl care to explain a little more?

Comment: it's quite simple...apply the plugin after the element is inserted in the DOM

Comment: @charlietfl thats what i thought I'd been doing

Comment: @charlietfl if it is quite simple, would you mind DEMONSTRATING how this is so, considering I've advised all the things I've tried which have failed, and every reference I can find to 'apply the plugin after' IS indeed by adding $(this).chosen() AFTER removing/adding the styles to the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply the plugin after you dynamically create elements.

This should work:

```
$newRow.find('select').each(function(){
  $(this).removeClass().removeAttr('id').css('display','block').next().remove();
  $(this).attr('name','itmCategory' + itm);
  $(this).attr('id','itmCategory' + itm);
  $(this).addClass('chosen-select-no-single');
  $(this).chosen();
});
```

**Note that the original row should be a native select element and not a chosen element.**

Comment: "should" being the operative word :( no dice. The rest has taken effect - class removed, id & name changed, class set again, however no chosen

Comment: Firebug console was returning no errors. Seems to be an issue with calling the chosen plugin on the class at document.ready, removing this and applying the plugin to each object via ID, still @ document.ready, half solves the issue. The other half is I've removed the chosen from the original row, hidden it, and cloned at document ready to show the first row.

Comment: The original row should be a native select element and not a chosen select element (I've just edit my answer).